# UINavigationController: Pop ViewController Animation pause for a while

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, navigation

I pop a viewcontroller with a full screen UIImageView(mode: .scaleAspectFill)

when I set `ImageView.layer.maskToBounds = false`, and pop out the viewcontroller, the pop up animation will pause for a while in the end

and when turn `ImageView.layer.maskToBounds = true` everything works fine.

here is the code

```
class ImageViewController: UIViewController {
    
    lazy var imageView: UIImageView = {
        let view = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "1.jpg"))
        view.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        view.layer.masksToBounds = false
        return view
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        view.addSubview(imageView)
        imageView.frame = view.bounds
    }

}
```

What is the reason?

Thanks :)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

What is happening is that the image is going beyond the `UIImageView`'s bounds and outside the ViewController. You can see the pause when the pop animation is finished but the ViewController is not yet dismissed.

If you want a full screen image it's the `UIImageView` that should fill the entire screen, but the image inside it should not escape its bounds.

Easiest way to do so is by setting:

```
view.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
```

where you are initializing your lazy imageView.

Remove the `masksToBounds` property which defaults to `false`, and you should be done!